# How to setup WordPress site locally with backup files downloaded from HostGator cpanel?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, cpanel

I was hosting two of my personal sites/blogs with HostGator for over 10 months. I didn't update my sites that often as I don't get enough time to write content for my sites .So, I decided to host my site through raspberry-pi or pc.

I downloaded full backup and home directory backup. Also, I installed WordPress locally. Now, I want to use my local WordPress setup to launch my sites by using files that I downloaded from HostGator cPanel but I dont know how to do that. Initially I spent sometime to get the solution from google as well as YouTube but directions were not clear. I tried to do it by myself but I was not successful.

Is there solution to this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a plugin for this.
Try *"Duplicator"* for example. It creates a backup for you and an installer file.

After downloading these files, you place them in your root directory and navigate to "localhost/installer.php" and everything gets set up as you had.